# c# main menu and mdi forms

Tags: c#, menu, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

So far in my life, as a .net developer, I have made heavy use of mdi forms to display particular "menu points" such as for instance "module 1" "module 2" and so on.

I have been doing this the following way:

- create a parent form with "isMdiContainer" set to "true"
- create a menu strip in in the mdi container
- create a child form implementing singleton in order for the form to be shown only once
- Add something like the following code to the mdi container:

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Myapp
{

public partial class MdiContainer : Form
{
    private module1 Module1Window;
    private module2 Module2Window;
    private module3 Module3Window;

    public FormContainer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Module1Window = modul1.getInstance();
        this.Module1Window.MdiParent = this;
        this.Module2Window = modul2.getInstance();
        this.Module2Window.MdiParent = this;
        this.Module3Window = modul3.getInstance();
        this.Module3Window.MdiParent = this;
        this.Module1Window.Show();
    }
    private void module1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Module3Window.Hide();
        this.Module2Window.Hide();
        this.Module1Window.Show();
    }       
    private void module2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Module1Window.Hide();
        this.Module3Window.Hide();
        this.Module2Window.Show();
    }
    private void module3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Module1Window.Hide();
        this.Module2Window.Hide();
        this.Module3Window.Show();
    }
}
```

}

Now, this obviously works fine. But it is a a pain to maintain. Everytime I want to add another child form I have to:

- implement Singleton
- create the corresponding property in the mdi container
- get the instance and set the mdi parent
- Hide the new form when other buttons are clicked
- Show the form and hide all other Forms when the corresponding button is clicked

Whats a more elegant or lets say efficient approach to archive this?

Comment: If I have understood correctly: you are using MDIs to handle different forms - but only displaying one form at a time. Why?

Comment: I don't think this will compile. Is it MdiContainer or FormContainer?

Answer (score 1):

When do you create the menu items? Are these dynamically created along with the child forms?

If so what you can do is create the form and add it to a list and assign the menu item's Tag property to the form. Assign all the menu items click event to the same handler and within the handler do this...

```
private void menuStrip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var menu = (ToolStripItem)sender;
    var viewForm = (Form)sender.Tag;
    foreach(Form childForm in _childForms)
        childForm.Hide();
    viewForm.Show();
}
```

This same handler can be used no matter how many forms you have.

Alternatively you can have a key as the Tag and have a `Dictionary<string, Form>` so you can more lazily create the forms, however the concept is the same.